# i was trying to make a help command using embeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

the help embed sends the first panel twice and i cant figure what is causing it,
its supposed to send 1 help embed that uses emojis to swap panels

````
const pagination = require('discord.js-pagination');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed-help',
    description: "sends embed test",
    
    execute(message, args){
      const page0 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#304281')
      .setTitle('page0')
      .setDescription('hello w0rld');

      const page1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('page 1')
      .setDescription('hello world 1');

      const page2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('page 2')
      .setDescription('hello world 2');

      const pages = [
        page0,
        page1,
        page2,
        ]

        const emoji = ["⏪", "⏩"]

        const timeout = '100000'

        pagination(message, pages, emoji, timeout)

      message.channel.send(pages)
    }
}```
````

Comment: try using  `async run (message, args)` instead of `execute(message, args)` and also check this [code.](https://github.com/thesportstacker/discord.js-v12-bot-tutorial-episodes-10-and-on/blob/master/Episode%2010/commands/help.js)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you are sending it in different messages, do this:

```
message.channel.send(page0);

message.channel.send(page1);
message.channel.send(page2);
```

But if you want multiple in 1 message, you need a webhook:

```
message.channel.createWebhook('New webhook', client.user.displayAvatarURL) 
    .then(w => w.send({embeds: [
        new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Embed1'),
        new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Embed2'),
    ]}))
```

client.user.displayAvatarURL makes the webhook pfp the same as the bot's pfp and the part that says 'New Webhook' is the webhook name, which you can change, and you should create the embeds in the w.send area